# Losing form values after validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

Using a ViewModel for validation:

```
public class CCvm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Name")]
    public string cardHolderName { get; set; }
}
```

My controller calls a task on post:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Pay(FormCollection form, CCvm model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And the View:

```
@model GCwholesale.Models.CCvm
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeSubPageLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Secure Checkout";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <div class="Payment">
         <label>Name on Card: </label>
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardHolderName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Cardholder Name Please", @Value = ViewBag.Name } })<br />
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardHolderName)
       <button class="submitCheckout">SUBMIT NOW</button>
      </div>
}
```

But when validation fails the data in the form goes away.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It would help if you can add your View code to the question.

Comment: I added the view code.....

Comment: Never attempt to override the `value` attribute when binding with html helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set `@Value = ViewBag.Name` inside **EditorFor**.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardHolderName, 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Cardholder Name Please" } })
```

Besides, you do not need **FormCollection** as a parameter because you already have **CCvm Model**.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Pay(CCvm model){
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Value = ViewBag.Name
```

You're not setting the ViewBag.Name, so it wouldn't have a value and would result in a blank input. Remove that and let the HtmlHelper set it based off the value in the posted model.